# How to get all links in a page for multiple URL and check whether it is broken or not and update in excel sheet?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an Excel with multiple page URL(example 5 to 10 URL's) in sheet 1. I need to open each page URL one by one and fetch all links in the page and update in next sheet of the excel ie sheet 2(first column) then check whether each link is broken or not and need to update the status in the same sheet 2(second column).Here is the code I was trying,

```
public class login {


    public static WebDriver driver;
     @DataProvider(name="URLS")
      //  @Test
        public Object[][] readFromExcel() throws IOException {

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("pagelinks.xlsx");

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

            int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int columns = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            Object [][]urls=new Object[lastRowNum][columns];

            for(int i=1;i<=lastRowNum;i++){
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
                    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    urls[i-1][j]=cell.getStringCellValue();
                }
               // String url = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                //System.out.println(url);
            }

    return urls;
        }

        @Test(dataProvider = "URLS")
        public void logInMethod(String url) throws IOException{

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","driver path");

            RemoteWebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

            driver.get(url);
            File src = new File("Pagelinks.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);
            sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
            List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            System.out.println(links.size());
            for(int i=0; i<links.size(); i++) {
                 WebElement element = links.get(i);
                 String urls=element.getAttribute("href");
                 verifyLink(urls); 
            }
        //  linkss();
            int cell =0;
            for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++) {
                WebElement alinks = links.get(i);
                String allinks = alinks.getAttribute("href");
                System.out.println(allinks);
                XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
                XSSFCell excelCell = row.createCell(cell);
                excelCell.setCellValue(allinks);
            }

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(src);
            wb.write(fout);
            wb.close(); 

        }

    public static void verifyLink(String urlLink) {
        try {
            File src = new File("Pagelinks.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
            XSSFCell excelCell = row.createCell(1);
             URL link = new URL(urlLink);
             HttpURLConnection httpConn =(HttpURLConnection)link.openConnection();
             httpConn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
             httpConn.connect();



             if(httpConn.getResponseCode()== 200) { 
             System.out.println(urlLink+" - "+httpConn.getResponseMessage());
             excelCell.setCellValue("PASS");
             }
             if(httpConn.getResponseCode()== 404) {      
             System.out.println(urlLink+" - "+httpConn.getResponseMessage());
             excelCell.setCellValue("FAIL");
             }
             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(src);
                wb.write(fout);

             }
             catch (Exception e) {
             }

    }
}
```

With this code I can open each Page URL and get all links in page and check whether it is broken or not but my problem is when I tried to write it to excel sheet I'm facing issue. The links are not updated in order wise also not all page links are updated in excel sheet. Can any one help me on this pls...

Comment: you keep creating row0 and cell0.  I would store your data in hashmap. (you can sort hashmaps)  Then write your excelfile once the webdriver code is finished.  I would also suggest creating a new file, not using the file you are reading from.

Comment: Big websites can have thousands of links. You need to check for duplications to avoid checking links more than once. Maybe separate external links. Better use some app like Xenu's link sleuth.

Comment: Besides there are more attributes than href able to contain a link.